# I have an answer to a question I've seen on here but I do not have enough reputation points to answer

Tags: discussion, support

So I have an answer to a question which I 100% understand as I was having the same problem as the poster of the question.
I'm unable to put up a reply because I don't have enough reputation points. A shame really as there's 8 replies and not one of them is correct.

Comment: You should normally be able to answer a question with only 1 reputation, unless the question is protected for some reason. Can you point us to the question?

Comment: Hi. Some questions here are protected because they have either attracted spam answers or too many answers which do not actually answer the question.  You need more rep to answer these. Sorry, but that's just the way it works here. Note that as a new user, you will not be able to see the deleted spam/non-answers, but they are there, just hidden to you.

Comment: yeah.. what question? `:)` Just based on the tags you used previously -- there are 82 questions referring to Illustrator and laser engraving.